# How can I make Ubuntu quiet for an autistic teen?

Tags: startup, scripts

My autistic son uses an Ubuntu computer to surf the web, watch videos and listen to music. He watches some videos and turns them too loud all night. I wrote a script which turns down the volume periodically using the `amixer` command.

I then added this to the Start-up Applications, but he found that and disabled the scripts and reboot the machine. Then I tried calling it in `rc.local` but cannot get this script which should run forever to work there.

Also I could not get it to work in `/etc/rc3.d` either. Maybe it is the script, but I cannot seem to get this to work, and there does not seem to be a way to lower the maximum sound output limit. Unless there is a way to remove the "Start-up Applications" from the gear menu, I have to go the hidden script route.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about using headphones? Physically disconnecting the speakers and using headphones would solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your command to the root crontab

```
# sudo crontab -e

# # edit the file and add this line
@hourly /usr/bin/amixer set Master 20

# Or whatever - this sets the volume every hour, on the hour,
# see `man crontab` and `man 5 crontab` for more detail
```